# Qt/QML - Positioner property not attaching to model delegate

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt Creator 4.6 on Linux. My problem can be reduced to the setup that is essentially the example provided in the documentation with some small changes:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-positioner.html

If I run the below code it draws some boxes, and clicking on each box should output its index. The code below works correctly for me as written. However, if I comment out TEXT 1 and uncomment TEXT 2, then clicking on the boxes outputs -1 for every box.

It seems like I have to use the Positioner in some way before the MouseArea or it won't work correctly (it can be used in the Text item or you can use it at the Rectangle level). I'm guessing it has something to with the MouseArea not being fully resolved until the actual click, and maybe if the compiler feels like nothing uses the Positioner it doesn't create it?

Is this behavior expected, and if so is it documented anywhere? In my real use case the workaround is to just use the Positioner to assign an index to an unused property or variable at the parent level so it's not too big a deal, but I'd like to understand it.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Grid {
        Repeater {
            model: 16

            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                width: 30; height: 30
                border.width: 1
                //color: Positioner.isFirstItem ? "yellow" : "lightsteelblue"
                color: "green"
                Text {
                    text: rect.Positioner.index  //TEXT 1
                    //text: "test" //TEXT 2
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: dragArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onPressed: {console.log(rect.Positioner.index)}

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that if you do not use it in the construction of the Item it is deleted, I have used a timer to set the example text and it also returns -1, it smells like a bug.